# calculate length and area of SVG shapes with transforms

Tags: svg

I'm working on .NET project. I need to calculate length and area of shapes in SVG file.

There are two difficulties:

a) Bezier curves - it seems formula is not trivial

and

b) transforms - before doing the calculation I have to apply all transforms

Can anyone recommend a library that does geometric computations on SVG files?
Can anyone recommend a code that applies transforms to SVG files and return raw values for each point in each shape?

Answer (score 1):

For bezier curves you can calculate length by converting the curve into line segments .You can use an algorithm given by DeCastelJau .
[algorithm is like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm)

Comment: I thought SVG had natively the path.GetTotalLength() that calculates lengths, no? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972191(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, SVG have its native method to calculate length of curves but it uses the basic algorithm of DeCastleJau

Answer (score 0):

If you open and save the files in the online SVG editor - 'SVG-Edit', it itself will remove any transformations( and will give you the raw values for each point  needed)

Also since SVG-Edit is opensource you can even search its source code to find the module which does that and use it.